# Spring MVC with AngularJS for presentation (is REST necessary ?)

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I plan to use Spring MVC for a JEE application and i'm still debating whether to use AngularJS or PrimeFaces for presentation. My question is :
I've done some research concerning AngularJS with Spring MVC and i have found pretty much everyone talking about using REST API in Spring to make the connection with AngularJS pages(?). Is that the only way to use these two technologies together ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not necessary. Your angular frontend will be expecting JSON data to render. As far as you can call your service be it any api and it (api) can return JSON it is good.

but rest is a preferred option for using angular as it is simpler to be configured.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as i mentioned in my other comment as part of the application i'm going to publish its services as SOAP WS, so my question should be can i make that happen (capturing backend SOAP message from Angular)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the spring controller/methods to be used as REST API, all you need to do is, annotate the controller with @RestController annotation.

Also in order to make the Java object to JSON and vice versa you can use Jackson API. Adding this snippet in your XML file and relevant dependency/jar in project will help you transfer data back and forth easily.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: @RestController is a useful convenience annotation, but it's neither necessary for a Rest API, nor is a thusly annotated controller automatically restful.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Thanks for the reply, just a little clarification : In my case i'll be publishing all of my services as SOAP WS, so i guess i should be asking if i can use SOAP for communication between Spring and AngularJS ? if so, how can it be done ?

Comment: @RedaN Spring certainly can do SOAP, don't know about Angular. But why would you want to use such a bloated protocol? I'd go with either Rest or JSON-RPC, it'll be a lot less messy and the performance will be better

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd i get what you're saying but the problem is I need to publish my services as SOAP WS no matter what, other than that i can use whatever i want. I guess in my case using PrimeFaces will be less messy and better performance wise ?

Comment: if you have to use SOAP then yes, Primefaces with SOAP is good. Have used it earlier.